# Best approach to toggle button & Placeholder for date?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, ux-designer

What is the best approach (i.e to add some icon or text etc) to show user that this section/button/menu is toggleable or we have more option on left or right on the controls? Right now I'm using << and >> on left and right of the buttons to toggle the buttons (shown in the picture on left top in red section).
Also what is the best approach (W.R.T user's experience perspective) to place a placeholder inside the textbox where I'm expecting date. Should I place it like dd-mm-yyy or should I place some real date like 01-01-2015. Also I'm using a span when user start typing in the field the span under the textbox gets visible showing the user what should he/she type in the box (shown in the picture in right section). Is it a good or bad approach ? Also for button I'm using text 'Get Data ' , what should be the more suitable words according to the scenario?
I'll be looking for your valuable suggesstions. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more options than can be easily shown, a "more" link may be easier to understand than using arrows

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuCzsh.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

As to placeholder values for dates. using "dd-mm-yyyy" would be preferable than using a real date for international users. In North America, we're used to the "mm-dd-yyyy" format. I believe in EU "dd-mm-yyyy" is more common.

Take a date like 01-01-2015. Does 01 refer to month or day? No idea. You can argue you can select a less ambiguous example like 15-01-2015. However the user still needs to do a little thinking to interpret 15 to be day and 01 is the month. Where as "dd" clearly means day and "mm" means month.

Other things to keep in mind for dates.

- For selection of recent dates, a date picker might be easier to manage than manually entering in a date
- If there are sensible default ranges, you should consider providing them so the user don't have to type in the range.

  - e.g. This Year, Last Year, YTD (year to date), MTD (month to date) etc

[image]
Example from Toggl web app

Comment: Thank you so much for these good suggesstions in such details. Its really helpful. I haven't thought about date picker yet. Yes its a good and easy option I think than to type in the box. Thanks.